# Missing (trainable) variables in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I encountered this issue in a larger code. And I reproduced it in the following test code. The trainable variables are not fully listed by tensorflow 2.1.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class FooLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, siz):
        super(FooLayer, self).__init__()
        self.siz = siz
        self.buildFoo(siz)

    def call(self, in_data):
        Foo0 = tf.multiply(in_data,self.FooTns0)
        FooList = []
        FooList.append(Foo0)
        for it in range(1,self.siz+1):
            tmp = tf.multiply(FooList[it-1],self.FooTns[it-1])
            FooList.append(tmp)
        return FooList[self.siz]

    def buildFoo(self,siz):
        self.FooTns0 = tf.Variable(1.0, name="TNS0")
        self.FooTns = []
        for it in range(0,self.siz):
            self.FooTns.append(tf.Variable(np.float32(it),
                name="TNS"+str(it+1)))
            self.add_weight("TNS"+str(it+1)) # Added after the first suggestion

class FooModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, siz):
        super(FooModel, self).__init__()
        self.flayer = FooLayer(siz)

    def call(self, in_data):
        return self.flayer(in_data)

model = FooModel(5)

for v in model.trainable_variables:
    print(v.name)

for v in model.variables:
    print(v.name)

x = np.arange(1.0,2.0,1.0)
x = x.astype(np.float32)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = model(x)
grads = tape.gradient(y, model.trainable_variables)

optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

The original output currently is only:

```
TNS0:0
TNS0:0
```

While the expected output is listing all 6 tensors, ''self.FooTns0'' and ''self.FooTns''.

**First suggestion**

After the first suggestion by @Wathek LOUED, I added the line `self.add_weight("TNS"+str(it+1))` and the output does include all other TNS. However, the gradient still does not find them and give error message as,

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['TNS1:0', 'TNS2:0', 'TNS3:0', 'TNS4:0', 'TNS5:0'] when minimizing the loss.
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `add_weight` method instead which is part of the `Layer` class?

```
for it in range(0,self.siz):
  self.add_weight("TNS"+str(it+1))
```

Comment: In tensorflow 1.*, we can use the tensor by name via ``get_variable``. However, this function is dropped in Tensorflow 2. Do you know any function to reach the tensor by name so that I can use it in ``call()``?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added the line and the code indeed output correct labels. However, the behavior of gradient is still not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a bug in TF2 as confirmed by TF group (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38211)

There is a temporary workaround, which returns the list of tensors from the `buildFoo` function to `__init__` explicitly. See [link](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/gulshanrana10/ea4520455f4591ed0364ea58aab229d6/38211.ipynb#scrollTo=E5fQvwtPByRJ) for example.